# Get the sum of values based on their background color - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It is possible in a google sheet to sum a row of data based on the formatting something like :

```
sumif(a1:d1, if background is green)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation:

I think the only way to achieve your goal is to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and in particular [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

The following custom function `totalColor(cells,color)` accepts a **cell** or a **range of cells** you want to [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and a **color** of your choice.

Here is the list of all available colors:

> redberry, red, orange, yellow, green, cyan, cornflowerblue,
> blue, purple, magenta, grey, white, black

The function returns the **total** sum of values of the cells for which the [background](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) colors are one of the **chosen color**.

---

### Solution:

```
function totalColor(cells,color) {
    
const jsonColor = {
    redberry: [ '#980000','#e6b8af','#dd7e6b','#cc4125','#a61c00','#85200c','#5b0f00'],
    red: [ '#ff0000','#f4cccc', '#ea9999','#e06666','#cc0000','#990000','#660000' ],
    orange:[ '#ff9900','#fce5cd','#f9cb9c','#f6b26b','#e69138','#b45f06','#783f04' ],
    yellow: [ '#ffff00','#fff2cc','#ffe599','#ffd966','#f1c232','#bf9000','#7f6000' ],
    green: [ '#00ff00','#d9ead3','#b6d7a8','#93c47d','#6aa84f','#38761d','#274e13' ],
    cyan:  [ '#00ffff','#d0e0e3','#a2c4c9','#76a5af','#45818e','#134f5c','#0c343d' ],
    cornflowerblue: [ '#4a86e8','#c9daf8','#a4c2f4','#6d9eeb','#3c78d8','#1155cc','#1c4587' ],
    blue:[ '#0000ff','#cfe2f3','#9fc5e8','#6fa8dc','#3d85c6','#0b5394','#073763' ],
    purple: [ '#9900ff','#d9d2e9','#b4a7d6','#8e7cc3','#674ea7','#351c75','#20124d' ],
    magenta: [ '#ff00ff','#ead1dc','#d5a6bd','#c27ba0','#a64d79','#741b47','#4c1130' ],
    grey:["#666666", "#999999", "#b7b7b7", "#cccccc", "#d9d9d9", "#efefef", "#f3f3f3"],
    white: ["#ffffff"],
    black: ["#000000"]
  };  
  
const colorArr = jsonColor[color]; 
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
const range = sheet.getRange(cells);
const hex_array = range.getBackgrounds().flat();
const values = range.getValues().flat();
var total = 0; 
hex_array.forEach((h,i)=>{                    
  if(colorArr.includes(h)){
  total += values[i];
  }                    
}); 
return total;  
}
```

and then use it as a simple formula in your sheet by defining the cell or the range of cells and the color with `""`, for example:

```
=totalColor("A1:D1", "green")
```

[image: example]

---

### Instructions how to create a custom function:

1. Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

[image: setup]

2. **Copy & Paste** the aforementioned code snippet into the script editor and click on the **save** button:

[image: example2]

Comment: Wow, that's amazing.

Two things, one I just needed to count the cells (how many) I figured that out by just doing total++; .

However, is it possible to NOT count a cell if the contents are struck out, as I use this to note a meeting which was cancelled, vs deleting the cell. I could of course just use a different color, but I use them to note the types of meetings.

Comment: @CliffStamp what do you mean by `if the contents are struck out` ? If it does not related to the answer, could you please post a new question as stackoverflow does not allow for follow-up questions? thanks

Comment: If you use "strikethrough" to cross out the text. I think :

const hex_array = range.getBackgrounds().flat();

that is what gets the background of the cells, there must be something like :

const format_array = range.getStrikethrough().flat();

Or some kind of :

const format_array = range.getFormat().flat();

which would allow a modification to a AND check in the forEach.

Comment: @CliffStamp I will work on that and update my answer later. But because the current answer provides a more generic approach on the color flexibility. It would be nice if you could post another question and I will be very much happy to answer it.

Comment: No problem, I will post up my attempt which fails for your amusement.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995400/google-sheets-counting-cells-based-on-strike-through-and-background-color

Comment: @CliffStamp sorry I didn't know that you were so close. Please check my answer on the new question.