# How to calculate total hours worked on an employee schedule with multiple different shift lengths

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, sum, schedule

I am trying to create a new scheduling spreadsheet and would like to automatically calculate each bartender's total hours for the week in column K.  However, there are multiple shift lengths each night.  How can I automatically pull an individual's total hours based on the specific shifts they worked each night?  Sometimes there would be a third 'mid-shift' between the opening and closing (as seen on night 3).  The number of shifts per week, shift lengths, and bartenders working will vary from week to week so I would like it to be universal.

My initial thought would be to calculate based on cell color but that doesn't seem to exist in Google Sheets.  I tried downloading an extension to pull cell color but that didn't do what I wanted it to. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

[Spreadsheet HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KXEGkVekA7s0jUo0bzXM64ZsofJ7MGLMaqa_SDaZo5g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far? Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the sum of values based on their background color - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972507/get-the-sum-of-values-based-on-their-background-color-google-sheets)

Comment: You have made a basic (and common) error in the developing your new spreadsheet - you didn't have a plan. Rather you spent ALL your time making the roster look nice BUT it's only now that you have thought about how to calculate shift hours, etc. Unfortunately, your roster is idiosyncratic (e.g using colours to identify shift types, etc) which complicates any solution. The answer to your question is simple: start again... forget formatting, factor in the formula calculations at the outset, develop a proof of concept, take that to a proto-type and then develop the full roster.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of your roster sheet doesn't lend itself to *easily* calculating shift hours by employee. That's not to say that it cannot be done with the layout as-is but the layout unecessarily complicates the task.

The main complicating factors are:

- shift types are identified by background colour
- the identification of shift types/hours/duration for each night is inconsistent (e.g. the "mid" shift is described only in "Night2") which makes it difficult to anticipate whether any given "night" will have a "mid" shift or not.
- the roster sheet includes blanks - for example: Cell F19 (Night2, Bar2) - this seems to be for aethetics

---

**Roster Layout**

This answer relies on a different, highly structured layout. The snapshot shows an example of "Night 3"; other nights are repeated above or below this. Rows 1&2 are frozen and not repeated.

[image: Roster snapshot]

- Roster assignments are made for each shift in each bar.

  - e.g Bar1-Opening, Bar1-Mid, Ba11-Closing, etc
  - data validation is used to select the barkeeper names for each/any shift.
- Shift times for each night are fully described.
- There is a summary of shifts/hours/total hours by shift type

  - there is also a "Total Hours" value.

**Calculations**

[image: calculations]

- I've moved the calculations to a different sheet for the sake of convenience.
- The formula for Night1 (Cell D15)is:
  `=ArrayFormula((if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$F$4:$F$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$B$7)+if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$I$4:$I$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$B$7)+if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$L$4:$L$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$B$7))+(if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$G$4:$G$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$C$7)+if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$J$4:$J$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$C$7)+if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$M$4:$M$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$C$7))+(if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$H$4:$H$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$D$7)+if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$K$4:$K$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$D$7)+if(iserror(vlookup($A$15:$A$34,'Shift sheet'!$N$4:$N$13,1,0)),0,1*'Shift sheet'!$D$7)))`
- Note: this uses "Arrayformula` so a single formula fills the entire column for all employees
- The same structure is used for other Nights" but cell references are changed to reference values for the relevant Night.
- The formula for the the sum of the Nights (Cell C15) is:
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(D15:D34="",0,D15:D34+E15:E34+F15:F34))`
  Again, this uses an Arrayformula but it sums columns D, E, F. You can edit it to add references to the column for other Nights.
- Some other formulas are described in the snapshot.
- The "Proof" is designed to ensure that values from the Calculation sheet agree to values from the Roster sheet.